# Need detail about Microsoft.Practices Library

Tags: wpf, eventaggregator

I want to refer to evengaggregator in my project and cannot find microsoft.practices.composite library easily. I could not find that in reference and tried few installation but no luck yet. I am using .net 4.0. Could you please help me to get start on how do I get microsoft.practices libraries on my machine? I am new to WPF and trying to join the dots here.

Thx,
Nikunj

Comment: [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) can be downloaded from codeplex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open below link and download prism library.

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com

after downloading go to Lib folder of downloaded prism and add reference of DLL to your project as required.

Comment: I have downloaded PRISM. But following are my doubts/questions

1. For an example Aggregator falls under Microsoft.Practices.PRISM - is this library ending with PRISM only specific for PRISM project or can be used it other live project too?

2. When I see MSDN, it says aggregator falls under Microsoft.Practices.Composite - but I could not find this dll on my machine?

I would rather want to use standard MS libraries than PRISM's libraries. I have doubt to go ahead in production with PRISM libraries.

Thx very much

Comment: actually when we use prism then no need to add Microsoft.Practices.Composite bcs alread added in PRISM library.  yes can be use in another project also.

Comment: BTW, how do I get Microsoft.Practices.Composite and other libraries like such? What should I download for that? I got EntLib but it had logging, exception etc but not composite